# Is this black mold? Do I have to vacate my home?

Tags: leak, safety, mold, water-damage

I am tearing out some wet ceiling in my kitchen. I found this on the underside of the drywall. Am I looking at black mold? If so, do I need to evacuate my family and pets from the house?

[image: Sheet of removed drywall with black substance on the paper backing]
[image: Another sheet of removed drywall with black substance on the paper backing]
[image: A pile of removed drywall sheets with black substance on the paper backing]

For reference, this kitchen is beneath a recently renovated bathroom. During the bathroom renovation there had been a leak into the kitchen below, and the contractors replaced the damaged kitchen ceiling and purportedly fixed the source of the water; however, we started to notice potential water damage again a few months later.  We weren't sure at first but when it became obvious we called in a plumber, who recommended we get the original bathroom crew in to fix some issues and, in the meantime, remove the ceiling in the kitchen so we could monitor any water coming in.  I started that process this afternoon, which is when I discovered this black substance on the paper backing of the drywall I started removing.

My most immediate concern is if this constitutes an immediate safety issue in which I need to get my family out of the house.

Comment: Pictures can only let us see it is black(what?)  It needs to be tested to tell the type of mold and if it is dangerous or just yucky.  If any members of the family not in the best of health, it might be an idea to reduce their time near there till testing comes back(should be fast).  Double plastic bag any stuff lying around with the black stuff.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to know for sure is to have it tested.

There are thousands of different mold types and only a few are the bad ones.

I use 3%hydrogen peroxide and water this solution breaks down the mold quite well.

The advantage to hydrogen peroxide over bleach come in several forms.

Peroxide kills the mold and then breaks back down into its components of oxygen and water oxygen. The other advantage is when done the house won’t smell like chlorine for days or weeks.

The one caution is if purchasing high purity hydrogen peroxide, always add the peroxide to water (this reduces the thermal reaction.

Comment: Yeah, there's a scene in *Outlander* where Claire is looking at hundreds of samples of moldy bread, hoping to find penicillin. There are a lot of molds.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica this is the last place I'd have expected to see a reference to _Outlander_... LOL

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you've already removed the moldy drywall.

The mold isn't the problem it is the spores and they are an inhalation risk.

As long as you can remove all the affected portions and take them out of the house then you have limited your exposure.

If someone is pregnant, immunocompromised or has other lung diseases then you'd need to worry more.

The only way to know the type of mold is to send to laboratory for microscopic analysis.  The question is more of how does the result change anything?  No mold is good to breath.  You'll want to wear a respirator when removing independent of what type of mold it is.  You'll want to avoid spreading the spores throughout the house.

In order to keep the air borne spore count down, mist the material before bagging or moving.  I had some mold growing on some drywall, I misted with water and then used some spray adhesive and put a sheet of poly over the affected area (sealing it in), then I removed a slightly larger area of the drywall as carefully as possible.  Bag it and take it out of the house.

Keep in mind that mold lives outside in dirt, on decaying tree leaves / etc.  The "fresh air" you let into your house can have higher spore counts than the interior air.  The main thing is to limit your exposure to mold spores.

Comment: But... but... the news tells me that "mold" is scary stuff! (+1)

Comment: Can you imagine if they reported on car accidents?  We'd be a car free society.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot tell by looking but you can send a sample out to be tested. In any case get as much of it as possible out of your home. There are many things you can spray to kill it if in fact it is mold. Hydrogen peroxide and chlorine bleach come to mind. While you are waiting for the results get the leak fixed and check-in-to some libality on the previous contractor, they may fix it at no charge for you. Get some fans blowing on the area 24/7 to completely dry it out. If you are really concerned you could go to the local motel for a few days. I have no clue as to where in this whole wide world you are located but you could possibly check with your local health authority, they may even do the testing. If there is a lot more consider hiring a Hazmat company. Immediately check with your homeowner insurance, they may cover it.

Comment: Get original contractors to pay for fixes, and get the insurance company involved (they may lean on the contractors with more weight than an individual can) are both good calls.